# JPA Database connection issue

Tags: java, jpa

So in school I am working on a RESTFUL-webapi. Until recently I only used 1 repository. Now that we finally have 2+ I changed how we called the EntityManagerFactory etc. I changed it to an abstract class so it could be called from there for every single repository.

```
public abstract class EntityController {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
    protected static EntityManager entityManager = null;
    protected static EntityTransaction entityTransaction = null;

    public void entityStart(){
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("research");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        entityTransaction.begin();
    }

    public void entityCommitAndClose(Boolean doCommit){
        if (doCommit){
            entityTransaction.commit();
        }
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Now the error I am getting is this one:

The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@dfd7dd11".

I did some googling and most people said it was a connection to the DB problem. However the Entitymanagers worked fine before I put them in an abstract class.

This is my persistence.xml file, located in the correct spot(resources/meta-inf)

```
<?xml   version="1.0"   encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
            version="2.1">
        <persistence-unit   name="research" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <!-- JPA    standard    -->
            <property   name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"   />
            <property   name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/groepswerk"   />
            <property   name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"  value="root"    />
            <property   name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"  value=""    />
            <property   name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"  value="create"  /> <!--drop-and-create-->
            <property name="openjpa.MetaDataRepository" value="Preload=true" />
            <!-- Hibernate  specific    -->
            <property   name="hibernate.show_sql"    value="true"/>
            <property   name="hibernate.xxx"    value="xxx"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So I was hoping mayby some of you could enlight me with what I did wrong?

Edit:

Source code for 1 of the repositories:
package app.repositories;

```
import app.models.Student;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentRepository extends EntityController implements IStudentRepository {
    final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ExamRepository.class);

    // to get a student by name
    @Override
    public Student getStudentByNumber(String number) {
        try {
            entityStart();
            TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student as s WHERE s.studentNumber=?1", Student.class);
            query.setParameter(1, number);

            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        } finally {
            entityCommitAndClose(false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    // to get a list of all students
    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        try {
            entityStart();
            TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student as s", Student.class);

            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        } finally {
            entityCommitAndClose(false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    // if student logs in, a student gets created
    @Override
    public void createStudent(Student student) {
        entityStart();

        Student newStudent = new Student(student);
        entityManager.persist(newStudent);

        entityCommitAndClose(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDownloadStatus(Student user, Boolean status){
        entityStart();
        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, user.getId());

        student.setDownloaded(status);

        entityCommitAndClose(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeUploadStatus(Student user, Boolean status){
        entityStart();
        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, user.getId());

        student.setUploaded(status);

        entityCommitAndClose(true);
    }


}
```

edit Catalina Logs:

```
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.repositories.EntityController.entityCommitAndClose(EntityController.java:26)
    at app.repositories.StudentRepository.getAllStudents(StudentRepository.java:42)
    at app.services.StudentService.getAllStudents(StudentService.java:16)
    at app.controllers.StudentController.getAllStudents(StudentController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 38 more

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.repositories.EntityController.entityCommitAndClose(EntityController.java:26)
    at app.repositories.StudentRepository.getAllStudents(StudentRepository.java:42)
    at app.services.StudentService.getAllStudents(StudentService.java:16)
    at app.controllers.StudentController.getAllStudents(StudentController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 38 more

07-May-2018 14:46:12.347 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage Error occurred during error handling, give up!
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.repositories.EntityController.entityCommitAndClose(EntityController.java:26)
    at app.repositories.StudentRepository.getAllStudents(StudentRepository.java:42)
    at app.services.StudentService.getAllStudents(StudentService.java:16)
    at app.controllers.StudentController.getAllStudents(StudentController.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you made the class abstract since it has no abstract methods. It only means no objects can be instantiated. Are there any previous exceptions?

Comment: No there are no previous exceptions. I basicly needed to use those 2 methods over 4 different classes. In my eyes the easiest way to do that is an abstract class @whbogado

Comment: It is most likely a database connection issue. With the information you provided no further diagnostic is possible.

Comment: @whbogado What type of information would you need? And as stated in the problem, everything worked before I changed it to an abstract class, weird a connection issue would appear right now

Comment: It would be worth adding the stack trace of the exception, and the source of one of your concrete classes.

Comment: So I added the class that I am calling, Student and I added the catalina logs that I recieved is this enough or do I need to add more?

Comment: You are getting NullPointerException at app.repositories.EntityController.entityCommitAndClose(EntityController.java:26) which means that the EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory are created but when you try to close one of them it is null. I suspect that the problem is that you are using static variables which are shared between instances, that is, when you close them in one instance they are close for all instances. It is OK to the EntityManagerFactory be static but the EntityManager must be unique for each database connection.

Comment: I am getting a nullpointer exception because I don't have an EntityManager, when I try to create the EntityManager I get the error that I mentioned in the problem above. The nullpointer is because I then try to close it while it doesn't exist. The issue is that I need to know why my creation of the EntityManager failed. The EntityFactory is created however! @whbogado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting a teacher about it, this is the solution I came up with. It does kinda change my concept of using the abstract class but it does fix all the issues.

```
public class EntityController {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

    static {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("research");
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void startTransaction(EntityManager entityManager){
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }


    public static void finishTransaction(EntityManager entityManager){
        if (entityManager.isOpen()){
            EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            if (entityTransaction.isActive()) {
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```